# What is the difference between mysql query cache and buffer pool?

Tags: mysql

İ am trying to understand the mysql architecture and I came acrosa two notions.
The first one is query cache, which I understood that it stores the queries that were run at least once, and if the query processor sees the query cached there, it no longer goes to the parser and takes the results directly to the cache.

But then, there is also the buffer pool, part of the Storage Engine buffer manager, which kinda does the same thing from my understanding.

So my question would be, if there is a cache in the logical layer, why do we need one in the physical layer also? İ am thinking that if a query is found in the query cache it will never be searched in the buffer pool, and if the query is not found in cache, then it will never be also retreived from the buffer pool. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

For query cache, you got it spot on. Its based on the raw text of the query mapping to the exact query results. It has major scaling problems which is why [MySQL-8.0 removed it](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/217577/why-mysql-remove-query-cache-in-8-0-version/217578#217578).

innodb buffer pool, is a storage of the low level data and index pages of the database. It ensures that all the recently used data is off disk and able to be queried without resorting to the much slower (by comparison to ram) storage.

So buffer pools serve all queries on the same data, while query caches only serve a particular query (at a large scaleability cost).

Comment: @GabrielaR  If you could imagine you had 1,000 queries in the Query Cache, humming away delivering data for a specific single table, now you need to insert, update or delete one row of data in that table, all 1,000 queries in the Query Cache are disabled and you are back with the overhead of accumulating Query Cache again.  Use of Query Cache is not healthy for a busy system, rely on your innodb buffer pool for high performance.

Answer (score 2):

Adding some context to @danblack's answer, query cache stores **the query and actual data associated with the query**. But in buffer pool which we call as innodb_buffer_pool stores **the physical (01,10) or low-level data or say pages**. Whenever query executes it checks in the buffer pool and if required data is not present then it will proceed towards the disk (i.e. your secondary storage) and puts data in the buffer pool.

With query cache, there is a disadvantage of invalidating query cache if query cache size being set quite high without analyzing the situations. By "**invalidating query cache**" I mean marking the data or entry in query cache as invalid because the underlying table has been changed by DML statements. I have personally experienced many times for example under "show processlist" when replication is stuck for long at this particular state i.e. invalidation query cache and once it invalidates all the entries, things start catching up.

> "Why do we need one in the physical layer?"

It is because having data in query cache can seriously impact the performance **IF** underlying table changes quite often which can affect the overall database performance. So if your table is not changing frequently query cache is useful. But now the concept of query cache has been removed in MySQL 8 (which is not a part of the discussion).

Answer (score 0):

Bufferpool is only used to store pages coming from the secondary store.
CPU can not fetch data from secondary storage so the Database management system makes a pool in RAM and then CPU keeps access data from this buffer pool from RAM.

and DBMS uses a replacement algorithm to replace pages from this buffer pool.

Cache of data is something else.
There are other data structs and techniques for data cache.